# Hide all but one tool tip

Tags: reactjs

I have the following tooltip component:

```
export interface ITooltipProps {
    Title: string;
    Visibility: boolean;
    Items: any[];
}

export const Tooltip: React.StatelessComponent<ITooltipProps> = (props) => {
    if (!props.Visibility) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <div className={css.toolTip} role="tooltip" style={{margin: props.Margin}} aria-hidden={props.Visibility}>
            <h1 className={css.toolTipHeader}>{props.Title}</h1>
            <ul className={css.itemList}>
                {props.Items.map((o) => {
                    return (
                        <li key={o.ID}>{o.Data}</li>
                    );
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};
```

That gets called from another component like:

```
<div onMouseOver={this.showtooltip} onMouseLeave={this.hidetooltip}>
    <Tooltip Title={strings.SecurityGroup_Label_ManagementOffices} ManagementOffices={offices} Visibility={this.state.IsToolTipVisible}  />
</div>

private showtooltip = () => {
    this.setState({ IsToolTipVisible: true });
}

private hidetooltip = () => {
    this.setState({ IsToolTipVisible: false });
}
```

The problem I'm facing is, since there's one `IsToolTipVisible`, if I have multiple tooltips in the component, it displays/hides it all the tool tips at once. How do I code this so that it only displays the item being hovered over?

Comment: Do you have any unique prop in the object u r binding to tooltip component?

Comment: There is an unique ID for each item in the `Items` array.

Comment: You can put a class to all tooltips. Then, hide all tooltips containing the class on the showtooltip function just before showing the current one.

Answer (score 0):

This can go into comments but adding it as an answer since it's big.

I can think of two ways now using your unique id (expecting it to be a id in the object we set to tooltip and not html id attributes)

1. you can use uniqueid and instead of saving a Boolean of istooltipvisible, save which one is currently visible. 
   And in the place where you check for istooltipvisible with Boolean, use something like eachuniqueid === currentvisibleid
   Using this, you will have only one tooltip at a time which could be a concern.
2. You can save a property istooltipvisible for each tooltip and whenever you have it visible, set it to true and when you close it, set it to false.
   This way you can manage multiple tooltips aswell.